# unix SED command to replace part of key value pair

Tags: unix, sed

We have requirement where i need to replace part of param value in our configuration file.

Example

```
key1=123-456
```

I need to replace the value after hyphen with new value.

I got command which is being used in other projects but i am not sure how it works.

Command

```
[test]$ cat test_sed_key_value.txt
key1=123-456
[test]$ sed -i -e '/key1/ s/-.*$/-789/' test_sed_key_value.txt
[test]$
[test]$ cat test_sed_key_value.txt
key1=123-789
[test]$
```

It will be helpful if some one can explain how the above command or is there a simpler way to do this using sed.

Comment: Is the formatting as you want it? I.e. is the value you want to replace actually containing asterisks? Your example and code seem inconsistent in this....

Comment: Which part of the command don't you understand? Please explain the parts you do understand.

Comment: I often use sed command to replace value, Format - sed -i -e '/valueToSearchFor/NewValue/ReplaceGlobalOrSpecificValue'  but the command in description has multiple delimiters '/'

Comment: Value which i want to replace will not have any asterisks, this is the command which i got from others but i don't understand how it works

Comment: Are you aware that you can [edit] your question to add info or fix problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a list of parts of that commandline, each followed by a short explanation:

```
sed
```

which tool to use

```
-i
```

flag: apply the effect directly to the processed file (whithout creating a copy of the input file)

```
-e
```

expression parameter: the sed code to apply follows

```
/key1/
```

"address": only process lines on which this regex applies, i.e. those containing the text "key1"

```
s/replacethis/withthis/
```

command: do a search-and-replace, "replacethis" and "withthis" are the next to explanations

```
-.*$
```

regex: (what is actually in the commandline instead of "replacethis") a regular expression representing a "minus" followed by anything, in any number, until the end of the line

```
-789
```

literal: (what is actually in the commandline instead of "withthis") simply that string "-789"

```
test_sed_key_value.txt
```

file parameter: process this file

I cannot think of any way to do this simpler. The shown command already uses some assumptions on the formatting of the input file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add to Yunnosch's answer that here the "replacethis" is a regexp:

```
-.*$
```

See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) for an overview of the syntax of sed's regular expressions by Gnu.
Asterisk means a repetition of the previous thing, dot means any character, so `.*` means a sequence of characters.
`$` is the end of the line.

You might want to be a bit more restrictive, since here you'd lose something in a line like this one for instance:

```
key1=123-456, key2=abc-def
```

replacing it by:

```
key1=123-789
```

removing completely the `key2` part (since the `.*` takes all characters after the first dash until end of line).

So depending on the format of your values, you might prefer something like

```
-[0-9]*
```

(without the `$`), meaning a sequence of numbers after the `-`

or

```
-[0-9a-zA-Z_]
```

meaning a sequence of numbers or letters or underscore after the `-`

Comment: True. You are nicely elaborating on what I summarised as "making assumptions".